# Jquery Event Conflict

Tags: jquery

Here's an example of the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/2pucon72/2/

my problem is when clicking on the `tablerow` I want to get the id and firstname however when I click on the `tr` it doesn't get me any value since the `blur` event is running... how can I fixed this problem? any suggestion guys? and the other thing is when I open the table and I want to click outside I want it to close that's why I put `blur` event there.

here's my code

```
//this will show the table if user click on the textbox
$('#demo').on('click', function(){
    $('#appendHere').attr('style','display:block');
});

// `(body)` because this element was loaded by jquery append.
$('body').on('click', '#dropdownTable tbody tr', function() {
    // alert($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html() + ' : ' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
    $('#demo').val($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
    $('#appendHere').attr('style', 'display:none');
});

//this will close the table when on blur.(self-explanatory)
$("#demo").blur(function(){
    $('#appendHere').attr('style', 'display:none');
});
```

[image]

Comment: you could try to prevent the blur event from closing your table and bind the close handler if clicked outside of your table or input

Comment: @eaCe but how can I close the table when I want to click outside?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ Hi sir, I have already created a scenario in jsfiddle...

Comment: where do you want to use the values? alert or something? what do u want to do with your values?

Comment: the fiddle contains just sample text. update fiddle exactly like your screenshot

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ I am using ajax to get the data... the example that I give is enough to fix the problem.

Comment: no no.. i mean, i need a sample data. just fill it with 3 columns in your demo. A single row with 3 column dummy data is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use to have a delay then in the `blur` event and instead of using `attr` method to show/hide just use the builtin methods `.show()/.hide()`:

```
$('#demo').on('click', function(){
    $('#appendHere').show();
});

$('body').on('click', '#dropdownTable tbody tr', function() {
    $('#demo').val($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
    $('#appendHere').hide();
});

$("#demo").blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('#appendHere').hide();
    }, 800);
});
```

#### [Fiddle Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/2pucon72/3/)